# Core data / Read only / Swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Working with core data, I have build the following files:
MyApp_DB.sqlite, MyApp_DB.sqlite-shm, MyApp_DB.sqlite-wal.

Those files will be included in the app bundle when shipping and they are rather big.
Once my app is published I want the database to be read only. Therefore there is no need to copy the files above outside of the bundle.

Here is my question, how should I configure core data in my app so that I have access to my database?

Things have changed with Swift 3, so the code I had working before does not function anymore.

I want my app to work with iOS 9 and iOS 10.

Comment: Maybe include the code that you are using and is not working along with a description of how is it not working on iOS9.

Comment: The old approach should still work. Swift 3 might require some syntax changes but the core functionality you need is unchanged.